# Issue with daisy chained arduinos and serial communication

Tags: arduino, uart, atmega328p, atmega32u4

I have a setup with a 32U4 based board and 2 daisy chained 328p based boards.
Boards are connected via 4 wires : VCC, GND, TX, RX
32U4 is powered by USB

Daisy chain is :

```
32U4 (RX)  <- (TX)  328p (RX)  <-  (TX) 328p
32U4 (VCC) -- (VCC) 328p (VCC) --  (VCC) 328p
32U4 (GND) -- (GND) 328p (GND) --  (GND) 328p
```

The 328p boards are sending every 1s a message on their uart TX port which is received by the board on their left.
Process is running ok but I have this strange behavior : when I upload a new version of the sketch on the 32U4 (via USB) and without powering off/on the serial messages chain get somethimes broken. This does not happen if I switch the 32U4 on/off.

Do you guys have an idea on why a sketch upload (reset) would produce such a behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: Chain broken sounds odd, check if the middle one is still sending. One likelihood would be a UART error bit getting set in the 32u4 if it starts receiving again mid-character, and serial code that doesn't clear it. You may need to examine the low level serial routines. How do you "know" the chain is broken anyway?  If you are waiting to hear something over the 32u4's USB, are you sure it has enumerated and your code is actually running?  Eg, make it give a "hello world" output before it starts proxying data.

Comment: Hi @ChrisStratton. The 32U4 is sending out every 1s a "heartbeat" message to USB serial so I know is it running fine.